# iptables routing port

Tags: networking, server, bash, iptables

Is it possible to redirect connections to a specific IP/port to an external IP/port?

Example:

```
Server A has the external IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Server B has the external IP yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

User sends a request to server A on port 25565, I want to redirect it to server B at port 25565 but people who connect to server B must have theirs IP adressess, not IP adress of server A.

This works, but all people who connect has IP adress of server A and I need that they will have their own IP adresses.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --dport 25565 -j SNAT --to-source yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

Comment: Using `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25565 -j MASQUERADE` instead of second command does not work either :/

Comment: Some help please? :/

Answer (score 0):

Using `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25565 -j MASQUERADE` instead of second command does not work either :/

Comment: Please this should be an answer to the question, put all comments in your OP either as an update or a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you need `DNAT` on server A with the following rules:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to <server B IP>`
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport 25565 -j SNAT --to <server A IP>`

Where:

- `<server A IP>` is the IP address on Server A the client sees
- `<server B IP>` is the IP address of host listening on `tcp/25565`

The first rule establishes:
Client ---> Server A ---> Server B (requests)

And the second rule establishes:
Server B ---> Server A ---> Client (responses)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, unfortunetaly, client doesn't connect with this. It has "signal" (I see that it is trying to connect), but that is all... On the other hand - thank you for help! :)

Comment: Hmm.. Please edit original post to include the output of the following commands:

`iptables -t nat -vnL`,

`iptables -vnL`,

`route -n`, and 

`sysctl -a | grep net.ipv4.ip_forward"`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nLpjNtqu

Comment: Are the clients connecting from the 10.8.0.0/24 (tun0) network? Or are they connecting from the Internet?

Comment: From the internet.

Comment: So ? ://///////